# Lots of duplicate classes for com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.12

Tags: leakcanary

I am using [leakcanary](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/):

```
// debugImplementation because LeakCanary should only run in debug builds.
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.12'
```

Building the app generates lots of duplicate class errors:

```
Duplicate class okio.AsyncTimeout found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.AsyncTimeout$Watchdog found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.Buffer found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.Buffer$UnsafeCursor found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.BufferedSink found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.BufferedSource found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.ByteString found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.DeflaterSink found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.ForwardingSink found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.ForwardingSource found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.ForwardingTimeout found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.GzipSink found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.GzipSource found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.HashingSink found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.HashingSource found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.InflaterSource found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.Okio found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.Options found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.Pipe found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.RealBufferedSink found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.RealBufferedSource found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.Segment found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.SegmentPool found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.SegmentedByteString found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.Sink found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.Source found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.Timeout found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
Duplicate class okio.Utf8 found in modules jetified-ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and jetified-okio-2.2 (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2)
```

Could anyone offer a tip on the its remedy?